# Laravel upgrade to 6 giving error facade root has not been set

Tags: php, laravel-6

I have my laravel app from 5.5 to 6.0 and am getting the following error.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set. in laravel-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:258
Stack trace:
#0 laravel-app/app/Exceptions/Handler.php(48): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('add', Array)
```

The error caused is due to below code

```
use App\Contracts\Facades\ChannelLog as Log;
use Monolog\Logger;
public function report(Exception $exception)
    {
        parent::report($exception);
        Log::add([Log::TRACE_DATA, Log::SECURITY_EVENT],
            Log::PROCESSING_ERROR, Logger::ERROR, __CLASS__, __FUNCTION__,
            'CMS Exception handler: ', $exception);
    }
```

If I comment the Log::add function the error is resolved but we need to have that function therein.
How can I resolve the issue?

Even when I try to run artisan commands it fails with the same error.

I have tried mostly everything that I found on internet, $app->withFacades(); in bootstrap/app.php would not work for me..am not using Lumen.

Comment: `App\Contracts\Facades\ChannelLog` this is not from laravel by default, you also need to provide this class.

Comment: Hi @AndySong Can you please elaborate, where should I provide this class?

Comment: it should in your `App\Contracts\Facades` folder `ChannelLog.php` file

Comment: @AndySong yes it is, I have ChannelLog.php in app/Contracts/Facades but am not sure how do I resolve the issue.

Comment: show the code to us.

Comment: Try to regenerate the classes as `composer dump-autoload` check the upgrade doc, if you misssing something https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade#the-input-facade